# Reset Event Handler for Touch Events

Tags: navigation, touch, touch-event

I'm having a problem with my website www.philipmadeley.com for "on touch" events in the nav. It seems to handle the first "touch" ok, but then doesn't work for the rest.  I tired several solutions, but I'm not that technical so i guess I might have overlooked something... anyway I can't seem to find an answer.  Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the event.originalEvent.touches or event.orignialEvent.changedTouches

and use instance 0

```
$("#div").bind("touchstart",function(event){

     event.preventDefault();            
     var touches = event.originalEvent.touches || event.originalEvent.changedTouches;
    if(touches.length == 1){

var touch = touches[0];

// Place element where the finger is horizontally
tx = touch.pageX ;
```

alert(tx);
}});

Comment: Thanks most appreciated :)